# access to member of object in php with value of parameter?

Tags: metaprogramming, php, variable-variables

i want return on of properties of `myobject` like this code :

```
class myobject{
   var $foo = 1;
   var $bar = 2;

   function getProperty($Field) {
       return $this->$Field;// this line have error
   }

}
```

$object = new myobject();

i call method like this

```
$object->getProperty("foo");
```

but line

> return $this->$Field;

have an error.

Comment: error : ' Undefined variable: selectedtitle , Cannot access empty property'

Comment: So then you are somewhere mistakenly calling `$object->getProperty("selectedtitle");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use magic method `__get`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get